# How to print out JPanel of Java Swing in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, printing, jpanel, screenshot

How do I print the screenshot I took from the application using some codes and have it printed? I know there's a method to print `jTable` but I want to print the whole `JPanel`, excluding the `JFrame` around it if possible :D

Comment: Define _print_. Print on paper? Print on console?

Comment: How do I define print?

Comment: Add the code you tried with.

Comment: @Tae "Define print"=what do you mean by print? print on paper? print con console?